# Remove html tags after animation is run with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div>   
    <span>H</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>

    <span>W</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>d</span>
</div>
```

I want to remove all of the `<span>` and `</span>` tags from the contents of the `<div>`.
However, the letters within the span are each appearing after a staggered `.fadeIn()` animation and I only want to remove the `<span>` tags *after* the animation is complete.

The final product should be `<div>Hello World</div>` after the animation has revealed each character.

JQuery 1.6+ solutions are welcome.

Comment: Can you show us the jquery code that you're using so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dsPJu/

**here is a working example**

this should do the trick... you just need to use a callback function

Comment: @samcone Thanks for your response!  If I understand your answer correctly, my question wasn't clear.  Once the final span is faded in, I want the div to contain only the text "Hello World" without any span tags.  I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @samcone This looks just about perfect.  But isn't $($(this).parent()) the same as $(this).parent()?

Comment: @timeEmit $(this).parent() does not return a jquery object ... you have to initialize it thus $($(this).parent())

Comment: I'll think you'll find $(this).parent() will return a jquery object... at least in version 1.4.2 upwards